# Next.js Is there a way to have built in css-sass enabled while adding less configuration?

Tags: css, webpack, sass, less, next.js

I want to use the **css/sass built-in feature** in Next.js while I want to add less configuration.

The **css/sass built-in** is fine but as soon as I add less to `next.config.js`, it **[disables](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/master/errors/built-in-css-disabled.md)** the feature so I have to configure them like before one bye one using:

```
@zeit/next-sass
@zeit/next-less
@zeit/next-css
```

Is there a way to keep the feature enable while adding **just** less config?

> Warning: Built-in CSS support is being disabled due to custom CSS configuration being detected. after adding less configuration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js disables **all** built-in CSS support if you have **any** custom CSS preprocessor.

So, if you add a custom plugin to process Less and need support for CSS and Sass, you would have to setup those plugins as well.

[Next.js webpack config source code](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/b8d075ef0e68b8407644b17813c510b4e30fd9ff/packages/next/build/webpack-config.ts#L1030)

Comment: I wondered if there is something that I don't know but it seems there is not. thanks